# $C^k$-maps between manifolds is a sheaf?

Tags: manifolds, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds

I know that the functor from the category of open subsets of a manifold $M$ to the Sets, taking an open set $U$ and associating to it the collection of $C^k$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ is a sheaf.

---

My question is a simple generalization;
If $M$ and $N$ are manifolds and $O(M)$ is the category of open subsets of $M$ with morphisms being inclusions, then is the functor:
\begin{equation}
   U \mapsto C^k(U,N)
\end{equation}
a sheaf also?

If so what is a good reference?

Comment: Yes. You can prove this.

Comment: Perfect!  Can you give me a reference to check against (I thought this was true).